# How can I remove all rows in which one of the values satisfies a condition? apply() not working

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe with two columns, and I want to remove all rows in which one of the values in each row is either smaller than 0 or bigger than a specified number (for the sake of argument let's call this 2000).

This is the dataframe

```
structure(list(xx = c(134.697838289433, 222.004361198059, 131.230956160172, 
206.658871436917, 111.25078650042, 241.965831417648, 171.46912254679, 
116.860666678254, 196.894985820028, 135.309699618638, 133.082437475133, 
185.509376072318, 718.998297748551, 745.902984215293, 752.655615982603, 
633.199684348903, 764.983924278636, 694.856525559398, 773.56532078895, 
757.32358575657, 709.924023536199, 658.863564702233, 733.076690816291, 
745.9306541374, 788.134444412421, 759.445624288787, 796.989170170713, 
632.952543475636, 746.103571612919, 715.296116988119, 766.899107551248, 
628.268453830605, 658.574104878488, 689.916530654021, 820.841422812349, 
709.097957368612, 793.109262845978, 716.713801941779, 726.83260343463, 
746.547080776193, 759.644057119419, 757.41275593749, 723.539527360327, 
839.816318612061, 795.655016954661, 766.245386324182, 756.300015395758, 
808.255074043333, 745.915083305187, 685.465492956583, 694.567959198318, 
786.919467838804, 699.521900871042, 749.041223560884, 700.079697765533, 
753.805501259023, 745.080253997501, 846.982894686656, 775.66384433188, 
809.39649823454, 841.009469183585, 790.987061753069, 792.441925234251, 
1377.97739642236, 1353.19738061511, 1259.94435540633, 1276.25060187203, 
1331.26106031956, 1227.68481147557, 1345.95561236514, 1309.51489973952, 
1285.62680259649, 1329.46388049714, 1256.00394500077, 1294.0505313591, 
1349.09440181876, 1294.72661682462, 1339.38577920408, 1277.114896541, 
1267.54884404031, 1291.32793111573, 1254.85565551553, 1298.78499697743, 
1283.89664572036, 1273.92831816666, 1310.221891323, 1327.89682404014, 
1310.81394400863, 595.342571560588, 689.892254230306, 562.390766853428, 
736.319251501976, 609.577261412134, 641.591997384705, 682.957658696869, 
580.320759093636, 560.64984978551, 643.487033739876, 688.457314818318, 
631.156743281308, 659.535909106305), yy = c(1169.70954243065, 
1259.830208937, 1172.21661417439, 1097.62724268622, 1198.15024522658, 
1231.90665701131, 1211.36196331211, 1152.4207367321, 1287.57553021171, 
1120.61366993258, 1234.70366243878, 1258.47454705197, 893.983957068268, 
994.99854601335, 916.330965835536, 947.536265806389, 950.345051732045, 
934.313361799171, 1018.76942964176, 918.182358835366, 1005.51128858608, 
967.577307930044, 997.239384198691, 995.866808447868, 962.292293255127, 
864.624084608006, 895.091604672023, 906.22162647536, 1024.45206885923, 
908.693026118345, 923.625774785301, 931.801569764776, 1007.88553380827, 
848.55309782664, 927.608364899483, 1024.60765786828, 1085.64295260059, 
1057.90632135992, 1195.30607038065, 1151.39888340311, 1168.2831257626, 
1137.15375447446, 1145.42393212912, 1108.89072769468, 1075.15451622384, 
1129.91711324634, 1191.94330388541, 1132.41649984784, 1210.89342724886, 
1100.60339252755, 1083.5987922884, 1056.69487941162, 1150.2707936581, 
1055.75678264632, 1055.53323667429, 1049.79655119467, 1166.86598024805, 
1141.82593378866, 1066.37755267981, 1160.55793904653, 1162.65728735716, 
1060.29360609309, 1107.40480300404, 1825.01445883899, 1802.95011068891, 
1692.84948509132, 1675.97166713074, 1758.10341887143, 1788.48414279738, 
1680.15824054313, 1756.01930833023, 1706.98458587119, 1770.57687329296, 
1692.21991398915, 1835.60585163662, 1790.6487914694, 1787.52076839767, 
1704.25313427813, 1735.96312434652, 1813.02044772293, 1847.21159474717, 
1725.63580525853, 1841.32016678, 1713.80845602987, 1770.39756152819, 
1747.72988313376, 1778.13110060636, 1786.3871288087, 6.01666671271317, 
19.2497357431764, 9.6964112500295, -3.23929433528044, 89.4863211231715, 
86.0082947221296, 42.7982120490919, 2.19886414532234, 12.8780844043502, 
30.694893442471, 7.58386594976601, 83.8385161493349, 36.4551491976192
)), row.names = 100:200, class = "data.frame")
```

First I create a function to eliminate points which satisfy the conditions.

```
routliers<-function(x){
  if(x>2000|x<0){
    rm(x)
  }
}
```

Then I use the apply function across the rows to eliminate the points using the above function (the above dput() is named cds).

```
cds<-data.frame(apply(cds,1,routliers))
```

But this eliminates all points

```
length(cds)
[1]0
```

Interestingly, if I replace the rm() function with print(), then I do print out the desired points when using the apply function, but I receive the error "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 2". Also, I am not sure when I use the apply() function that the specified function applies to both columns of data, as I am not seeing any data points in print() that satisfies the condition for ONLY the second column of points. The first column is x co-ordinates, and the second column is y co-ordinates. I think the error "arguments imply differing number of rows:0,2" suggests that only the first value in the row is being tested against the function.

How can I write code in which rows are eliminated if one or more of the data points satisfies my condition?

This is easy to do when the columns are separate vectors, (x<-x[!condition]) however I cannot add them together again easily so I prefer to do this on a dataframe of points.

Comment: `rm()` is for deleting whole objects from your environment - it doesn't work on pieces of objects like rows or columns. To drop rows, as you say `x<-x[!condition]` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this code works for you, with `df` being the data you shared:

```
#Code
new <- df[!rowSums(df < 0 | df>2000) > 0, ]
```

Or this:

```
#Code 2
new <- df[which(apply(df,1,function(x) sum(x<0 | x>2000))==0),]
```

Comment: Yes, both work, excellent! Though I do not understand how. Could you explain your logic please?

Comment: @OpenSauce Sure, it is a way to use logic results from functions. So, we test at row level which values satisfy some condition and then we filter to get the expected output. Please let me know if that was clear enough for you!

Comment: I think I understand, similar to the above answer using TRUE or FALSE logic, we eliminate the rows that satisfy the condition. Is this correct?

Comment: @OpenSauce Yes, you are right :) but the built-in functions as `rowSums()` or `apply()` can help you to avoid some steps like loops or others

Answer (score 1):

Let's make your function return `TRUE` for an outlier and `FALSE` for not an outlier. And it can be vectorized:

```
is_outlier = function(x) {
  x > 2000 | x < 0
}
```

Here's how we'd use this to drop rows with outliers in a single column:

```
cds[!is_outlier(cds$xx), ]
```

For two columns, we can combine the `is_outlier` results with `&` or `|`. I can't tell from your text whether you want to remove rows where `xx` AND `yy` are outliers, or remove rows where `xx` OR `yy` are outliers. So pick the appropriate version:

```
cds[!is_outlier(cds$xx) & !is_outlier(cds$yy), ]
cds[!is_outlier(cds$xx) | !is_outlier(cds$yy), ]
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the boolean function method. However, ````cds[!is_outlier(cds$xx) | !is_outlier(cds$yy), ]```` Eliminates only 1 row. After experimentation, I found that ````cds[!(is_outlier(cds$xx) | is_outlier(cds$yy)), ]```` Is the correct method.